# What are the troubleshooting steps/tools for C# to Native interop?

Tags: c#, interop, native

I have an SDK that is written primarily in C#.  We have some native code that was written for security and performance reasons.  We use DllImport to interop with the native code.  There are a few functions that I get an "`Unable to find an entry point named '...' in DLL '...'.":"`" error.  I have verified that the function that is not found is exported.  I have verified that it does not have a mangled name.  I have verified that the parameters line up.  I have tried a couple different calling conventions in the DllImport attribute.  I guess I can keep trying this sort of randomly, but I am hoping there is a more direct approach.

Does anyone know of a tool or method to get more information in a case like this?  How confident should I be that the dll has been located?  Would I get this exception if the parameters are wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Pat O

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue, but I still don't have a better approach than sort of rooting around to see what's what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if this works in the Full Framework or not, but you can try:

http://blogs.msdn.com/stevenpr/archive/2005/06/22/431612.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find the exported functions in a C++ DLL.  This will help ensure you're trying to import the right name, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I have verified that the dll exports are as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I use [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(VS.71).aspx) to get my list of exports...

Good luck!